# Работа с речью в C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, при работе с распознаванием речи возникает ошибка. Код программы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace VoiceRecognizationDemoApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        Choices clist;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clist = new Choices();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        clist.Add(new string[] { "hello", "how are you", "what is the current time", "open chrome", "thank you", "close"});
        Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(clist));
        try
        {
            sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            sre.LoadGrammar(gr);
            sre.SpeechRecognized += sre_SpeechRecognized;
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    private void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text.ToString())
        {
            case "hello":   
                ss.SpeakAsync("Hello Mihail");
                break;
            case "how are you":
                ss.SpeakAsync("i am doing great Mihail. How about you?");
                break;
            case "what is the current time":
                ss.SpeakAsync("current time is" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                break;
            case "thank you":
                ss.SpeakAsync("not at all");
                break;
            case "open chrome":
                Process.Start("chrome", "http://www.google.com/");
                break;
            case "close":
                Application.Exit();
                break;
        }
        textBox1.Text += e.Result.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sre.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Для работы с речью скачивал Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1 и Microsoft Speech API 5.1. Думаю что проблема находится именно в них. Делал все по примеру [на Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xug793JfqSE). Прошу помочь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка возникает здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

stack trace:

> Поток 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x1f34) завершился с кодом 0 (0x0). 
>   "VoiceRecognizationDemoApp.vshost.exe" (Управляемый (v4.0.30319)):
>   Загружен 
>  "C:\Users\Михаил\documents\visual studio 
>   2012\Projects\VoiceRecognizationDemoApp\VoiceRecognizationDemoApp\bin\Debug\Voic
> eRecognizationDemoApp.exe",
>   Символы загружены.
>  Поток '<Без имени>' (0x39c) завершился с кодом
>   0 (0x0).
>  Первый этап обработки исключения типа 
>   "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" в System.Speech.dll 
>   Первый этап обработки исключения типа "System.NullReferenceException"
>   в 
>     System.Speech.dll 
>  Поток 'vshost.RunParkingWindow'
>   (0x9a0) завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
>  Поток '<Без имени>' (0x1a68)
>   завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
>  Программа "[8644]
>   VoiceRecognizationDemoApp.vshost.exe: Трассировка     программы"
>   
> завершилась с кодом 0 (0x0). 
>  Программа "[8644]
>   VoiceRecognizationDemoApp.vshost.exe: Управляемый 
>   (v4.0.30319)" завершилась с кодом 0 (0x0).

Убрал

```
catch(Exception ex)
```

Вот что вышло:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жму "Продолжить" возникает другое исключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю от администратора. Всеравно появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Подробная информация об использовании оперативной  (JIT) отладки 
>   вместо данного диалогового  окна содержится в конце этого сообщения.
>   
>   ************** Текст исключения ************** 
>  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): В результате 
>   вызова компонента COM возвращена ошибка в формате HRESULT E_FAIL.    в 
>   System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.Initialize(SapiRecognizer 
>   recognizer, Boolean inproc)    в 
>   System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.get_RecoBase()    в 
>   System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.RequestRecognizerUpdate() 
>   в VoiceRecognizationDemoApp.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, 
>   EventArgs e) в c:\Users\Михаил\Documents\Visual Studio 
>   
> 2012\Projects\VoiceRecognizationDemoApp\VoiceRecognizationDemoApp\Form1.cs:строка
>   45    в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    в 
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    в
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ************** Загруженные сборки ************** mscorlib
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- VoiceRecognizationDemoApp
>       Версия сборки: 1.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/VoiceRecognizationDemoApp/VoiceRecognizationDemoApp/bin/Debug/VoiceRecognizationDemoApp.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34250 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34239 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Speech
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Speech/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Speech.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.34230 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- mscorlib.resources
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms.resources
>       Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
>       Версия Win32: 4.0.30319.36213 built by: FX452RTMLDR
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
>
> ************** Оперативная отладка (JIT) ************** Для подключения оперативной (JIT) отладки файл .config данного приложения
>   или компьютера (machine.config) должен иметь значение jitDebugging,
>   установленное в секции system.windows.forms. Приложение также должно
>   быть скомпилировано с включенной отладкой.
>
> Например:
>
> При включенной отладке JIT любое необрабатываемое исключение
>   пересылается отладчику JIT, зарегистрированному на данном компьютере,
>   вместо того чтобы обрабатываться данным диалоговым окном.

Comment: Если вы приведёте stack trace, а не скриншот, наверное, будет легче найти проблему.

Comment: самому захотелось сделать нечто подобное )))

Comment: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` - вероятно изменилась версия dll, или подгружается несовместимая версия, проверьте референс ссылки приложения, откуда он берет эту dll. Как вариант, положить актуальные версии в выходной каталог сборки, и попробовать с ними.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
> }
> ```

Убираешь эту дрянь и дебажишь. Заодно увидишь нормальный stack trace, а не информацию об успешном завершении.

---

И попробуй запустить программу с правами администратора.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте SpeechRecognitionEngine явно инициализировать, с указанием языка, текст то у вас английский, а язык де-факто наверняка русский :)

`SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));`

[Описание](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/hh378426(v=office.14))